# Editing a records not hiding the div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

while adding a record if i select the one of the value from dropdown then some of the divs are hiding and while insertion the data is inserting successfully into database.

Here the problem is while editing the same record which i have inserted by default it is showing the fields which i have added.

For Example: when user selects open plots from dropdown then i am hiding these two divs total_bathrooms and car_parking but when i edit if the dropdown value is open plots it should not display these two divs total_bathrooms and car_parking but here it is displaying.

Inserting A Record:

```
 <select class="custom-select-box" name="property_type" id="property_type"required>
                                <option>Property Type</option>
                                <option value="1-BHK">1 BHK</option>
                                <option value="2-BHK">2 BHK</option>
                                <option value="3-BHK">3 BHK</option>
                                <option value="Villas-Duplex">Villas-Duplex</option>
                                <option value="Houses">Houses</option>
                                <option value="Open-Plots">Open Lands</option>
                            </select>


<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="total_bathrooms">
                                <div class="field-label">Total Bathrooms</div>
                                <input type="text" name="total_bathrooms" id="total_bathrooms"  placeholder="Total Bathrooms"  maxnumber="1"><span id="errmsgs"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="car_parking">
                            <div class="field-label">Car Parking</div>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="car_parking" value="Available">Available
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="car_parking" value="Unavailable" >Unavailable
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#property_type').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == 'Open-Plots')
  {
    $("#total_bathrooms").hide();
    $("#car_parking").hide();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#total_bathrooms").show();
    $("#car_parking").show();
  }
});
});
```

Editing a Record:

```
<select class="custom-select-box" name="property_type" required="" id="property_type">
                                    <option value="1-BHK">1 BHK</option>
                                    <option value="2-BHK">2 BHK</option>
                                    <option value="3-BHK">3 BHK</option>
                                    <option value="Villas-Duplex">Villas-Duplex</option>
                                    <option value="Houses">Houses</option>
                                    <option value="Open-Plots" selected="selected">Open Lands</option>
                                </select>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="total_bathrooms">
                                <div class="field-label">Total Bathrooms</div>
                                <input type="text" name="total_bathrooms" id="total_bathrooms" value="" maxnumber="1" required=""><span id="errmsgss"></span>
                            </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="car_parking">
                                <div class="field-label">Car Parking</div>
                                <input type="radio" name="car_parking" value="Available">Available
                                <input type="radio" name="car_parking" value="Unavailable">Unavailable
                            </div>
```

jquery is same for both adding and editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your check on when the page loads as well.  Your current code only checks when the select list is changed.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    showHide();
    $('#property_type').on('change', function() {
       showHide();
    });

    function showHide(){
       if ( $("#property_type").val() == 'Open-Plots')
       {
          $("#total_bathrooms").hide();
          $("#car_parking").hide();
       }
       else
       {
          $("#total_bathrooms").show();
          $("#car_parking").show();
       }
     }
});
```